# Glue Spark Scala Script to check if file exist in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am new in writing AWS Glue script and I would like to check if there's a way to check if a key, file, or pathname already exists in S3 bucket using Spark/Scala?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried boto3 https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2 with pyspark?

Comment: Hi but I have to work with Scala. Is there a way to make it work with Spark/Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a library like [this](https://github.com/seratch/AWScala), to check if a file exists in S3. You would have to upload the jar to S3 so you can reference it in your Glue Job as an external library.

Another way would be to use the Filesystem.Get method like this:

```
var sc = new SparkContext()
if(FileSystem.get(URI.create("s3://s3bucket/"), sc.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path("s3://s3bucket/")))
{
     println("File exists")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way not to use a library? like a simple call ".exist", like importing with boto3 (can't use since I am using Scala not Pyspark)

Comment: @CharmeeLee I added another way without a library :)

Comment: oh thank you! I am confused if hadoopConfiguration will work but it seems it will!

Comment: If my answer helped you, an upvote and an accept would be appreciated!